# Is the following html layout possible using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, layout

[image]I tried making the html layout on the picture. The light blue col-md-2 divs contain images, the darker blue col-md-4 is an image too. The pink divs contain text. Please give a simple html layout which does what's on the picture.

Comment: Yes, this layout is possible, as you have displayed in your image. Do you have any code that you're struggling with?

Comment: Probably.  Maybe.  Why don't you try it and see, and if you run into problems, THEN ask a specific question.

Comment: I have 2 hours of trying, and stopped for today. Will try some more tomorrow. Sorry, don't want others to do work for me.

Comment: This layout is definitely possible with Bootstrap and it is actually what Bootstrap excels at. However, you will need to actually post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but each '.row' has to have columns inside of it equal to 12 columns. So the parent column divs equal 12 col-md-8 and col-md-4. But the child divs inside the col-md-8 div does not equal 12. So those would have to be 8 and 4 also. Or 9 and 3... as long as it equals 12. It just depends on what the content will be. Also you can contain all that in a div and center that div to the view port.

But that layout is possible. Below I focused on and made an example on the grid system layout you should be using.

I've colored the columns so you can see the grids layout. Hope this helps!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='main-container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-8' style='Background-color: red; height: 300px;'>
      col-8
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-8' style='background-color: blue; height: 80px;'>col8</div>
        <div class='col-xs-4' style='background-color: black; height: 80px;'>col4</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-4' style='background-color: black; height: 80px;'>col4</div>
        <div class='col-xs-8' style='background-color: blue; height: 80px;'>col8</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-8' style='background-color: blue; height: 80px;'>col8</div>
        <div class='col-xs-4' style='background-color: black; height: 80px;'>col4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-4' style='background-color: blue; height: 300px;'>col-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent. The trick I could not find was putting .row-s into the big col-8 and treating these rows in col-8 as a full rows again (splitting them into col-8 + col-4). Great idea. Thank you. The rest (aligning and other small issues) is CSS, no big deal.

Comment: Awesome!!! glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

of course it's possible. Here is a totally functional example:

[Example in Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/loruit/pen/NxPbmB)

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #E5FF5E;
  padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px !important;
}
.row {
   min-height: 1000px;
   background: red;
}
.vertical {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.rows {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#left-container {
  background: #6AFF98;
  height: 1000px;
  display: table;
}
#right-container {
  background: #6FFFE9;
  height: 1000px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #left-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 767px) {
  #left-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {

}
#r1c1 {
  height: inherit;
  background: #FF76FD;
}
#r1c2 {
  height: inherit;
  background: #A1FFE8;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="left-container" class="col-md-8">
        <div class="vertical">
          <div class="rows">
            <div id="r1c1" class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div id="r1c2" class="col-md-4"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="rows">
            <div id="r1c1" class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div id="r1c2" class="col-md-8"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="rows">
            <div id="r1c1" class="col-md-8"></div>
            <div id="r1c2" class="col-md-4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container" class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted the other answer, because it came first and it was pure twitter-bootstrap, without much CSS styling added. (Some  additional styling is needed of course to align the divs vertically and horizontally, but I prefer to use less tweaking and stick more to the bootstrap styles). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All columns in Twitter Bootstrap are floating elements. So you can't get content centre aligned just by Twitter Bootstrap classes. You can try styles like `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the blocks: col-md-8 and col-md-4.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh14mar/qc9zfpo6/